# JavaScript access CSS class by its name?

Tags: javascript, css, properties

I have to access CSS class by name, and the code below works. However if I try `hui["myclass"]` or `hui[".myclass"]` instead of `hui[0]` it cannot find it.

```js
function change_class() {
  var hui = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
  hui[0].style["color"] = "#ff0000"
}
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: #00aa00;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" onclick="change_class()">Some Text</div>
```

**EDIT:** I need to be able to acess as i described on line 1 i dont want to acess trough individual elements on page, but directly to stylesheet by class name.

So you all saying i cannot access to stylesheet by class name only by index?

Comment: That'd be due to `0` being an index.

Comment: How do i access by name though?

Comment: Can't you just use jQuery and `$('.myclass').trigger()`?

Comment: Don't know it's support level, but [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) is an option.

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName()` is another way.

Comment: It's getElementsByClassName(). Elements, plural.

Comment: I dont want to access trough any elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't access them by the selector - it's a simple list. You first had to build an index for it:

```
// assuming those are the right rules (ie from the right stylesheet)
var hui = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;

var styleBySelector = {};
for (var i=0; i<hui.length; i++)
    styleBySelector[hui[i].selectorText] = hui[i].style;

// now access the StyleDeclaration directly:
styleBySelector[".myclass"].color = "#ff0000";
```

Of course this is not a fool-proof method, there could be

- multiple selectors like `.myClass, .myOtherClass`
- multiple occurences of one selector (though it doesn't matter, the last declaration overwrites previous styles anyway)

and instead of blindly assigning the `color` property you first should check for existence of the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bergi is right:
You first have to build an index for the style list.
BUT take care: 
If there is more than 1 stylesheet you first have to **loop over the stylesheets**. 
So I like to improve Bergis solution:

```
var styleBySelector = {};
for (var j=0; j<document.styleSheets.length; j++)   {
  var styleList = document.styleSheets[j].rules || document.styleSheets[j].cssRules;
  for (var i=0; i<styleList.length; i++)
    styleBySelector[styleList[i].selectorText] = styleList[i].style;
 }

// And then invoke or set the style you wish like this:
styleBySelector[".myStyle"].color = "#ff0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
```

will return an array of elements which match.

You could also use something along the lines of:

```
<body>
    <div id="changethese">
        <div class="myclass" onclick="change_class()">Some Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myclass">div two</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var changeTheseDivs = document.getElementById('changethese');
changeTheseDivs.getElementsByClassName('myclass')
```

To change only the class within the selected div.

However, support for this method only works back to IE9, so if JQuery is an option, it might be best to use that.

**Edit:**

I believe I misread, it looks like you want to change the actual CSS rule itself as opposed to changing CSS on the elements. You could, in theory, write a function that will find rules by name for you and change their properties. I guess it would look something like this (untested, should work):

```
function findAndChangeCSSRule(ruleName, newRule, newProperty){
    var mysheet=document.styleSheets[0];
    var myrules=mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules: mysheet.rules
    for (i=0; i<myrules.length; i++){
        if(myrules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase()==ruleName){
             targetrule=myrules[i];
             break;
        }
    }
    targetrule.style[newRule.toString()]=newProperty;
}
```

then call it with:

```
findAndChangeCSSRule('my_class', 'color', 'red')
```

Comment: I dont want to access trough any element.

Comment: I saw that sorry for misreading, check out the edit, it should at least get you started.

Comment: @JohnSmith Trough means what exactly in this context?  I'm assuming you mean -through-, given that a trough is a food container, among  other things that have nothing to do with code.

Comment: @Daedalus He wants to manipulate the stylesheet, not the inline styles.

Comment: I don't think you should use `toLowerCase`, that could make a huge difference

Comment: Thx, but other dude was first.

Answer (score 0):

To change the established rules, this is one approach:

```
// the [2] index is only because that's where JS Fiddle
// puts the user-entered CSS (from the CSS panel).
var sheets = document.styleSheets[2].rules,
    classString = 'body',
    props = ['color'], // requires a 1:1 relationship between two arrays...ugh
    to = ['#0f0'];

for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].selectorText == classString) {
        for (var c = 0, leng = props.length; c < leng; c++) {
            sheets[i].style[props[c]] = to[c];
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WhGnD/).

And a slightly improved alternative (an object rather than two arrays, that require a 1:1 relationship):

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets[2].rules,
    classString = 'body',
    propsTo = {
        'color': '#0f0'
    };

for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].selectorText == classString) {
        for (var prop in propsTo) {
            if (propsTo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                sheets[i].style[prop] = propsTo[prop];
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WhGnD/1/).

Answer (score 0):

To access the class from javascript you just need to create a classist, if it's not there.

```
document.querySelector("myDiv").classList.add("className");
```

This adds the new class to the div with the specified class name.

Else:

```
document.querySelector(".className");
```

Answer (score -1):

`(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules || document.styleSheets[0].rules)[0].style.color = '#ff0000'`
 should work.

[Quirksmode CSSOM (DOM CSS) compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html)

Comment: That's what i had in beginning just different format now instead of [0] i need name, please read carefully next time.